# How to add id attribute to a div-EXTJS3

Tags: extjs, extjs3

I have a component whose 'id' is auto-generated. I want to replace that id with my own for styling purposes. I'm unable to use class for styling as the class is used by bunch of other components.

```
Ext.query('.q-superdate-field')
```

that results into:

```
<input type="text" size="16" autocomplete="off" id="ext-comp-1100" name="ext-comp-1100" class="x-form-text x-form-field q-superdate-field x-form-empty-field x-trigger-noedit" readonly="" style="width: 100px;">
```

I want to change the width of the input field using id. Is there a way to replace exisiting 'Id' and create one of our own

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to change id dynamically

```
Ext.select('.q-superdate-field').elements[0].id = 'newId';
```

Note: this is not best approach my answer is just for you question.